# How to generate folder and files inside it with a command in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation

In all projects I work with a similar design pattern so what I've noticed is that visual studio code I always have to create folder and files inside the folder repeatedly and its been time consuming a lot .

What I need to know is How can I create folder and two files inside of it with specific names by pressing a shortcut key or with a command in visual studio code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using [Folder Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Huuums.vscode-fast-folder-structure) ([repository](https://github.com/Huuums/vscode-folder-templates)) extension for visual studio code .